# how to create a YES NO notification for time?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a formula that shows hours and minutes of how long it took to notify a client. I need to create another cell to say `YES` if that notification is 4 hours or longer.

I currently have the formula as this:

```
=IF(OR(AND(MOD(P2,1)>=TIME(4,0,0))),"YES","NO")
```

Where `P2` is hours/minutes of how long it took to notify the client.

This formula works the way I want it to except if it is equal to 4 hours, it is returning `NO`, instead of `YES`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like it could be simplified to just `=IF(P2>=TIME(4,0,0), "YES", "NO")`.  Not real clear from your question what isn't working for you, or what the format of P2 is (i.e. 4.5, 4:30, text, number, etc.).

Comment: Oh, wait... I think I figured out the MOD. It's a hacky way of extracting the time portion from an Excel date/time serial number. Since the hours/minutes/seconds are encoded as a fraction of one day, MOD 1 would strip the date off and only leave the time.

Comment: But... now I still can't figure out *why*. I mean, if the formula in P2 only returns hours and minutes, that shouldn't even be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's something you're not telling us, I see no use for OR, AND, or MOD in your formula. Actually, I can think of *no* conditions whatsoever under which OR or AND have any purpose in that particular formula - they are multi-conditionals meant to evaluate more than one criteria and return a TRUE/FALSE if any (for OR) or all (AND) conditions are TRUE. However, you only have *one* conditional so OR and AND will always evaluate just the same as the conditional itself. MOD's purpose here is still a bit confusing. Chances are there's something in those bits and/or in you source data that's corrupting your results.

Myself, I prefer to have Excel give me a simple Boolean TRUE/FALSE instead of "Yes"/"No" since it makes using the cell's value in other formulas a bit easier. For example, if B1 has a Boolean, I can just use `=IF(B1,"RUNNING SLOW!","Timely response!")` instead of `=IF(B1="Yes","RUNNING SLOW!","Timely response!")`. It's also simpler to write the initial formula too - consider `=A1=B1` vs. `=IF(A1=B1,"Yes","No")`.

As long as your times are formatted as actual times, this should work just fine to return a Boolean TRUE/FALSE (assume time is in A1):

```
=A1>=TIME(4,0,0)
```

[image]

If you *really* want that "Yes"/"No" response, throw it in an IF:

```
=IF(A1>=TIME(4,0,0),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Upon further consideration, I think I may have guessed the involvement of MOD (OR and AND seriously still don't have any place there).

If you're using MOD to strip the date from a date/time value, that *might* be causing your problem. I'm not exactly sure on how, but I'm expecting it possibly has something to do with leap years/minutes/seconds since Excel stores dates & times based on the time elapsed since 1/1/1900 (ish). There's probably also some rounding errors involved somewhere along the way.

Speculation aside, here's the *right* way to strip the date portion out for your formula:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))>=TIME(4,0,0)
```

And, if you're still in love with "Yes"/"No":

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))>=TIME(4,0,0),"Yes","No")
```

For that matter, we could even simplify further:

```
=HOUR(A1)>=4
```

Or...

```
=IF(HOUR(A1)>=4,"Yes","No")
```

Note that the possible values for HOUR cap out at 23. But, if you're using an actual date/time format for your source data anyway (and your formula pretty well implies that you are) that won't be an issue.